# How do I access Rundeck Job execution number inside script?

Tags: rundeck

Similar to accessing job options like:

```
#!/bin/bash
my_var=@option.my_var@
```

is there a way to access general job execution properties?

Specifically, I am deploying a docker container and would like to leverage the execution number to inject a link back to the rundeck job execution that was responsible for deploying said container

Comment: should have included an example of what I'm trying to generate: https://rundeck.local.com/project/DeployDev/execution/show/EXECUTION_NUMBER_HERE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that use

```
echo @job.execid@
```

You can see all options putting @job. in the inline script and Rundeck shows you all the options (autocomplete).